# Sending/receiving messages to a net core worker service in a secure way

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, security, .net-5, webapi

I'm creating a [net core worker service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/workers) to periodically fetch and process various data. This will run as a Windows Service on an application server.

In some cases I need to tell the worker to "process data now" and fetch limited information about it's internal workings.

The process communicating with the worker (basically a manager desktop app) and the worker itself will run on the same application server. I can't think of a better way other than turning the worker into an ASP.NET Core WebApi with a [hosted service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio). Such a webapi would only be bound to a localhost address, but how should I secure it so that it's only listening to a requests from my desktop app?

I'd like to avoid certificates so I could keep deployments simple.

Comment: What does `secure` mean in this context? Do you mean you don't want any other processes on the same server to be able to eavesdrop on HTTP traffic between your manager application and your API? Do you mean that you want to authenticate users so that only a specific user (your manager application) can issue commands? Do you mean something else?

Comment: Sounds over-complicated. To define "secure", you'll need to define who are you trying to defend against and why. Then think about what that hypothetical attacker might be capable of doing, like decompiling your application since they have access to the binaries. Then you might decide that all of that work is just "security theatre", so you might as well just "authenticate" by passing a hard coded value like 7 as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

To protect web API, you can add authentication. For example, you can use IdentityServer4 to add OAuth with **Client Credential** flow for your web API, then before you can desktop can call your web API, it need to acquire the token first.

Below are the helpful links for your reference:

[Tutorial: Create a web API with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-authentication-support-to-a-web-api-21)

[Protecting an API using Client Credentials](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html)